# Arduino concat char pointer

Tags: c++, arduino, char, nmea

I am struggeling with something for quite a while now, I am trying to generate a NMEA message based on some variables, now these 0,0,0 needs to be a variable, So I need to concat my variables to this message char pointer. any suggestions how?

```
char * message = "$CONFI,0,0,0";
Serial.println(generateChecksum(message),HEX);

int generateChecksum(char *nmea_data)
{
    int crc = 0;
    int i;

    // ignore the first $ sign,  no checksum in sentence
    for (i = 1; i < strlen(nmea_data); i ++) { // removed the - 3 because no cksum is present
        crc ^= nmea_data[i];
    }

    return crc;
}
```

Comment: Not using pointers and literal strings is  good start. Perhaps use the Arduino standard [`String`](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/variables/data-types/stringobject/) class instead.

Comment: Thanks, although I read all over the internet to avoid to use the string class since they are using quite a bit of your Arduino, also I've no clue on how to generate my CRC then.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The String class is bloated and wasteful.   I have never used it because of this.  In fact, I have never used any library for the Arduino ever.  Even on the STM32 I prefer direct register programming and perhaps an LL call, maybe.  But never HAL.  Abstraction = waste and when space matters, waste often cannot be tolerated.  I would wager that most designers with patents in embedded design (as I have) would agree.

Answer (score -1):

Here's a pretty standard way of doing it in C. Format the string with `sprintf`, but use the version that shouldn't overrun the buffer, and use the version that gets format strings from flash instead of RAM:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define NEMASIZE  30
char nemamessage[NEMASIZE+1];
... etc ...
n = snprintf_P(nemamessage, NEMASIZE, F("$CONFI,%d,%d,%d"), a, b, c);
// now check n!!
```

This is in the AVR libc library: https://www.nongnu.org/avr-libc/user-manual/group__avr__stdio.html

And I have no idea how big NEMA strings can be, so adjust as needed! :-)